# How sqlplus "show parameter" result column without wrapped while glogin.sql empty

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

The question is how show tidy result in one server when glogin.sql is empty?

Did not want to use this code in glogin.sql for every db server:

```
-- Defaults for SHOW PARAMETERS
COLUMN name_col_plus_show_param FORMAT a36 HEADING NAME
COLUMN value_col_plus_show_param FORMAT a30 HEADING VALUE
```

[TO-BE result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R48LC.png)

[IT-IS now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1bf7.png)

Thanks.

Comment: By setting the width?

Comment: Without setting width can show compact result too in one server. TO-BE Image

Answer (score 0):

You can make one global file or several glogin files(glogin1.sql, glogin2.sql) and get files using the http protocol or ftp.

```
    oracle@esmd:/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/db/sqlplus/admin> sqlplus / as sysdba

    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Jun 27 07:49:34 2019

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

    SQL> @http://xxxx.yyyy.zzz/glogin.sql
    [esmd] sys@esmd> show parameter target

    NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
    ------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
    archive_lag_target                   integer     0
    db_flashback_retention_target        integer     1440
    fast_start_io_target                 integer     0
    fast_start_mttr_target               integer     0
    memory_max_target                    big integer 2352M
    memory_target                        big integer 2352M
    parallel_servers_target              integer     32
    pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 0
    sga_target                           big integer 0
    [esmd] sys@esmd>
    [esmd] sys@esmd> @http://gift.krw.rzd/glogin1.sql
    [esmd] sys@esmd>
```

I can add call global `glogin.sql`  from local `glogin.sql`

```
--
-- Copyright (c) 1988, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. 
-- All rights reserved. 
--
-- NAME
--   glogin.sql
--
-- DESCRIPTION
--   SQL*Plus global login "site profile" file
--
--   Add any SQL*Plus commands here that are to be executed when a
--   user starts SQL*Plus, or uses the SQL*Plus CONNECT command.
--
-- USAGE
--   This script is automatically run
--
@http://xxxx.yyy.zzz/glogin.sql
```